# keras - Error when checking target with embedding layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, embedding

I'm trying to run keras model as follows:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu',input_shape=(286,)))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax',input_shape=(324827, 286)))
```

This code works, but if I'm trying to add an embedding layer:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(286,64, input_shape=(286,)))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu',input_shape=(286,)))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax',input_shape=(324827, 286)))
```

I'm getting the following error :

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (324827, 1)
```

My data have 286 features and 324827 rows.
I'm probably doing something wrong with the shape definitions, can you tell me what it is ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to provide the input_shape in the second Dense layer, and neither the first one, only on the first layer, the following layers shape will be coomputed :

```py
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Embedding, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

# 286 features and 324827 rows (324827, 286)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(286,64, input_shape=(286,)))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
model.summary()
```

returns :

```
Model: "sequential_2"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding_2 (Embedding)      (None, 286, 64)           18304     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 286, 10)           650       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 286, 1)            11        
=================================================================
Total params: 18,965
Trainable params: 18,965
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

I hope it's what you're looking for